# How do I store the changes to a git repository in another server-side repository?

Tags: linux, git

I'm making changes to the Linux kernel for my particular ARM board.

I've cloned this repository: `http://arago-project.org/git/projects/?p=linux-am33x.git`

I want to commit the changes I've made, and push them, but to my own server, not to the arago server. I'm currently doing a diff on my work directory and committing the diff to my own server side repo. Is there a more elegant approach to this?

Note that I'd like not to clone the entire arago repo on my server. The changes I'm making are trivial, this repo is not. Based on the answers below, I've done this:

```
$ git remote add myrepo ...`
$ git fetch myrepo
$ git checkout -b mybranch origin/v3.2-staging
$ git push myrepo mybranch
```

I was expecting that nothing would be uploaded, since nothing has been committed yet. But all of v3.2-staging started getting uploaded. What I want to do, is to commit my local changes to mybranch. And only that should get pushed to myrepo/mybranch. What kind of `checkout` will permit this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the branch you are on is `mybranch` and the remote you want to hit you will call `myremote`

- Add the remote
  `git remote add myremote [GIT_URL|PATH|URL|SSH-LINE]`
- Push your branch (and potentially any changes to it)
  `git push myremote mybranch`

You then have to choose and manage yourself which you want to check out from or track in the future

- If you later want to fetch ALL of your remotes together instead of `git fetch` do `git remote update`
- If you want to continue to keep `myremote/mybranch` synchronized with an upstream `origin/upstream` branch but push it to `myremote/mybranch` then you will be best served by altering the config so that it pushes by default to `myremote` :
  `git config remote.origin.pushurl user@user.com:repo.git` (Checking for better way to do this part)

Suggest that you take a read of the working with remote repo's section of the git-book http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes

Comment: Thanks. The book link is useful. It will help me "actually know what I'm doing" with git, a concept I don't always follow :p

Comment: Highly highly highly recommend reading it or at least skimming it

Comment: OK, so I did the following:

`$ git remote add myrepo ...`
`$ git fetch myrepo`
`$ git checkout -b mybranch origin/v3.2-staging`
`$ git push myrepo mybranch`

I was expecting that nothing would be uploaded, since nothing has been commited yet. But all of v3.2-staging started getting uploaded (I think).

What I want to do, is to commit my local changes to mybranch. And only that should get pushed to myrepo/mybranch.

Comment: @diskless It did exactly what it should have.  You checked out a local branch called `mybranch` based upon the contents of `origin/v3.2-staging` (and depending on your config also tracking it).  You then pushed this branch to your `myrepo`.  If it didn't already exist there it would upload this branch to that repo.  Whether you have committed anything yet to your local branch or not is irrelevant, what's relevant is only whether that branch existed on the remote you are pushing to and if it would be a fast-forward merge.

Comment: @diskless I amended my answer to highlight that I think you got tripped up by "your changes"; effectively your changes the first time is the branch's existence.

Comment: understood. How can I continue to track the changes to v3.2-staging on the arago server, while only pushing my commits only to myrepo?

Comment: Assuming what you are saying is "keep your branch up to date with respect to the upstream `origin/v3.2-staging`" then you will want to set it up such that you fetch and merge `origin/v3.2-staging` into your branch and then push your branch to `myrepo`.   This is already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4523496/is-it-possible-to-pull-from-one-repo-and-push-to-other-one .  Again I would suggest reading a bit more to understand what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
git format-patch -1 <commit_SHA>
```

Answer (score -1):

add your server as a new `remote`, using `git add remote`; then when you push/pull you can specify which server you communicate with.

You may also want to change the default remote using `git config` to change `master.remote` and `master.merge` (git actually allows different defaults for push and pulls, which you may want to use here).

Comment: Ah, this looks _exactly_ like what I needed. Let me research `git add remote`. And it would be great to `pull` and `push` to different servers. Thank you so much!