# push to heroku after push has been made to git repo

Tags: git, heroku

I have a situation in where I have two remotes. Confirmed by running `git remote -v`

Now, I already did `git push`
But now, I want to push to heroku as well. So I used `git push heroku master`. However, it shows already-up-to-date.

Please note that I already deployed once to heroku prior to this git push heroku. 
How can I push/deploy  my changes ?

Comment: How did you deploy to heroku? It is important because heroku needs code to be pushed in order to deploy your code. That might explain the reason of what you experienced.

Comment: I used windows CLI to push and then ran some commands present here  https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-command-line
Then I deployed with reference from  https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs#deploy-the-app

Comment: It seems that you already pushed to heroku to deploy your code. Therefore `git push heroku master` command did not find any updates since it was already gone to heroku.

Answer (score 0):

Check your `git branch -avv` output.

It is possible that the master branch could be linked ([through its push url](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4523625/6309)) to the `heroku` remote.