# Git globally redirect fetch server, but also update the origin server?

Tags: git, git-config

Suppose I want to redirect all fetch upon url `https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git` to a local repo `~/.Specs`, and `push` also updated to the origin url, how to do?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1722807/git-convert-git-urls-to-http-urls) seems partly solve my problem, but this config affect both `fetch` and `push`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can specify a custom Specs repository in your Podfile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
git remote set-url --push origin user@example.com:repo.git
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4523625/1254812

Comment: Thanks, but this is mostly a question for `git`. I know how to use a private mirrored specs repo.

Comment: Oh. [Here](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-push.html#_named_remote_in_configuration_file).