# Is the Visual Studio Sync function synching my repo to upstream or fork?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I a contribute to an open source project on github and i am using visual studio with a forked repo on my github account of the original code. My question is that in visual studio i get a prompt to sync. What i dont understand is that what is it syncing it with? is it syncing the local repo on my comuter with the repo on my fork? or is it syncing the fork with the actual original repo of the project i am contributing to? or is it syncing both the code on my local comp, and my github repo, with the original code?

Comment: local repo with fork

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set your local repository to:

- clone the upstream original repository
- [change the push url to push to your fork](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4523625/6309)

(if you are the only one working on your fork)

But by default, a repository fetch and push to the same repository, which in this case is the one you own (meaning the one you can push to): [your fork](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6286877/6309).