# How do I create a second git remote on my local computer?

Tags: windows, git

on windows

I have a complex script that uses a config file.
My working directory we'll call \dev\pvcs
There is a remote repository on github

When a commit is made, tested and pushed to github I then need to deploy the script to the operating folder on a different drive -- let's call it \ops\pvcs

When I start to work on a new branch, I need to pull the config file from ops folder to the dev folder, and when I'm done I need to push the script and the config file to the ops folder.

I have two .cmd files to do this.

it seems to me that I should be able to use git to do this, but everything I see about setting up a remote, the remote is on a server somewhere.

What is the best way to do this using git?

Answer (score 0):

You can either:

- add a second push URL, in order to [pull from one repo, and push to another](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4523625/6309)
- a a second remote

  ```
    git remote add ops \\ops\pvcs
  ```

You can push what you need to ops with `git push main ops`